# Loading Module on Mac -Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, github

*Very New to Coding* I am trying to use a package from GitHub which I installed with pip, and I keep getting an error when using the functions. I want to be able to access my food for the given day.

This is the code I am trying to run. It should print the given day's calorie information.

```
import myfitnesspal


client = myfitnesspal.Client('username')

day = client.get_date(2013, 3, 2)
print(day)
```

This is the error I'm getting.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myfitnesspal.py", line 1, in 
    import myfitnesspal
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myfitnesspal.py", line 4, in 
    client = myfitnesspal.Client('username')
AttributeError: module 'myfitnesspal' has no attribute 'Client'

Also, this is the link to the GitHub if that helps https://github.com/coddingtonbear/python-myfitnesspal

Answer (score 0):

This may be silly but can you check if you did import the package correctly using `pip freeze` or `pip list`

If not and you can't install the package use : `sudo pip install myfitnesspal`

If you did, maybe try importing Client :

```
from myfitnesspal import Client

client = Client('username')

day = client.get_date(2013, 3, 2)
print(day)
```

Comment: I ran sudo pip install myfitnesspal, and it just said the requirements are satisfied already.

Comment: When importing Client, I get "ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'myfitnesspal'"

Comment: And when I pip list, the package is listed there

Comment: Have you maybe imported the wrong package the first time. You should uninstall the package and install it again. You can also check in your libs folder the package and see if myfitnesspal has the module Client